# twbsPagination is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

The pagination page numbers looks weird and lengthy. I want to display only some of the page numbers in frontend. my code It's working ok, but not good when there's large numbers of pages. so i'm using twbsPagination in function renderPagination. when i run my code i'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).twbsPagination is not a function`. twbsPagination source is script:src pagination.js. but when i run twbsPagination separate without any function it's working fine. how can i run twbsPagination with my code?

index.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<script src="homer/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="desk/vendor/pagination/pagination.min.js"></script>
<script src="desk/components/approved2.js"></script>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="approvedList">

  </tbody>
</table>

<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul class="pagination"></ul>
</nav>
```

index.js

```
const localURL = "http://localhost:8000/"
// output Html
const Story = document.querySelector('#approvedList');
const pagination = document.querySelector('.pagination');

$(function () {
    var page = 1,
        records = 1,
        totalRecords = 0,
        search = '';

    // Run on page load
    fetchData();
    setInterval(fetchData, 2000);


    // data filtering
    $("#search-input").keyup(function (e) {
        let value = e.target.value
        fetchData(search = value);
    });

    // Show Records limits
    $("#records").click(function (e) {
        let value = e.target.value
        fetchData(records = value);
    });

    // Previous Page
    $('[aria-label="Previous"]').click(function () {
        if (page > 1) {
            page--;
        }
        fetchData();
    });

    // Next page 
    $('[aria-label="Next"]').click(function () {
        if (page * records < totalRecords) {
            page++;
        }
        fetchData();
    });
    // data fetching from API
    function fetchData() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8000/api/approved/",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                page: page,
                records: records,
                search: search
            },
            success: function (res) {
                totalRecords = res.count
                Story.innerHTML = '';
                res.results.map((object) => {
                 
                    Story.innerHTML +=
                        `<tr>
                            <td> ` + object.id + `</td>           
                            <td>${object.id}` + object.title + `</td>          
                        </tr>`;
                })
                Pagination();
            }

        })
    }

    function Pagination() {
        // let pagesNumbers = Math.ceil(totalRecords / records);
        let pagesNumbers = Math.ceil(totalRecords / records);
        $('#pagination').twbsPagination({
            totalPages: pagesNumbers,
            visiblePages: 5,
            onPageClick: function (event, page) {
                $('#page-content').text('Page ' + page);
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add twice the jQuery library.

I don't know the **pagination.min.js** and **approved2.js** libraries but I know you can add the **twbsPagination** as follow:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twbs-pagination/1.4.2/jquery.twbsPagination.min.js"></script>
```

Moreover, this line is wrong:

```
let pagesNumbers = Math.ceil(totalRecords / records);
```

**pagesNumbers** needs to be at least 1.

The snippet with your code:

```js
const fakeData = {
    data: [{
        row: 1,
        name: 'a'
    }, {
        row: 2,
        name: 'b'
    }, {
        row: 3,
        name: 'c'
    }, {
        row: 4,
        name: 'd'
    }, {
        row: 5,
        name: 'e'
    }, {
        row: 6,
        name: 'f'
    }, {
        row: 7,
        name: 'g'
    }],
    totalRecords: 7
};
// output Html
const Story = document.querySelector('#approvedList');
const pagination = document.querySelector('.pagination');

$(function () {

    var page = 1,
            records = 1,
            totalRecords = 0,
            search = '';

    // Run on page load
    fetchData();

    // data fetching from API
    function fetchData() {
        totalCount = fakeData.totalCount;

        Story.innerHTML = '';

        fakeData.data.slice((page - 1) * records, page * records).map((object) => {
            Story.innerHTML +=
            `<tr >
        <td>${object.row}</td>
        <td>${object.name}</td>
        </tr >
            `;
    })
    renderPagination();
}

function renderPagination() {
    let pagesNumbers = Math.ceil(totalRecords / records) || 1;
    $('.pagination').twbsPagination({
        totalPages: pagesNumbers,
        visiblePages: 5,
        onPageClick: function (event, page) {
            $('#page-content').text('Page ' + page);
        }
    });
}

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twbs-pagination/1.4.2/jquery.twbsPagination.min.js"></script>


<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="approvedList">

    </tbody>
</table>

<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination"></ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: i'm getting same error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).twbsPagination is not a function` i don't know why this happened?

Comment: i am using django python framework so maybe that's why it's not working... dear i just want to show only some page numbers in pagination my code is working fine but the page numbers is gone weird and lengthy... if you have any solution for it please explain me. thanks in advance

Comment: yes that's why i'm using `twbsPagination` it's the only hope for me to what do i want to do  ... please take a look my Question again if you have the other solution. please tell me

Comment: i don't know why i'm getting this error dear i have spend my 3 day's on it but its not working. would you like to tell why this happening? why i'm getting this error?